# How to remove Wordpress Console Warnings?

Tags: wordpress, console

I’m using Humming Bird Pro & Smush pro. I have managed to get rid of numerous numbers of console warnings. However, still getting some which I need to remove badly, but getting no way out.

Here it goes:

```
This page uses the non standard property “zoom”. Consider using calc() in the relevant property values, or using “transform” along with “transform-origin: 0 0”. http://www.popuanime.com.au
JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 3.3.2 jquery-migrate.min.js:2:709
Some cookies are misusing the recommended “SameSite“ attribute 2
Cookie “” will be soon rejected because it has the “SameSite” attribute set to “None” or an invalid value, without the “secure” attribute. To know more about the “SameSite“ attribute, read https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite cross_domain_static.html:1:1388
Relative positioning of table rows and row groups is now supported. This site may need to be updated because it may depend on this feature having no effect. jquery.min.js:2:51844
This site appears to use a scroll-linked positioning effect. This may not work well with asynchronous panning; see https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Mozilla/Performance/ScrollLinkedEffects for further details and to join the discussion on related tools and features!
```

Can anyone help me out with this?